# Rails wrap_parameters weired behavior, working on one controller and not working on another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two different controller, both inherited from `ApplicationController`, `class PagesController < ApplicationController` and `class CommentsController < ApplicationController`.

Posting on `page#test` copy all posted params to another hash attribute :

```
# POST '/pages/test' :
{ "awd":"awd" }

# result :
{
   "awd": "awd",
   "action": "test_post",
   "controller": "pages",
   "page": {
       "awd": "awd"
   }
}

# POST '/comments' :
{"awd":"awd"}

# result :
{
    "awd": "awd",
    "action": "create",
    "controller": "comments",
    "comment": {}
}
```

Comment routes create by `resources :comments, only: [:create]`, `post '/comments' => 'comments#create'` do the same.

P.S. : No `before_filter` or any extra code in any of them, all requests are json, `wrap_parameter.rb` has `wrap_parameters format: [:json]`.

**Edit**

There's just one difference between those controllers, `CommentsController` generated with `rails g scaffold ...` and `PagesController` generated with `rails g controller ...`

**Edit 2**

`self._wrapper_options` in `CommentsController` `self._wrapper_options` has value of

```
{
    "format": [
        "json"
    ],
    "include": [
        "_id",
        "created_at",
        "updated_at",
        "content",
    ],
    "name": "comment"
}
```

That made the problem, but why when I didn't set include in wrap_parameters, rails added that?

Answer (score 3):

> On ActiveRecord models with no :include or :exclude option set, it
>   will only wrap the parameters returned by the class method
>   attribute_names.

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/ParamsWrapper.html

I'm guessing that "awd" is an attribute on the Page model, but not on the Comment model. If you really want to send that JSON to your comments controller, try adding something like this:

`wrap_parameters :comment, include: [:awd]`